# Picking good/bad items from a set.

Tags: probability

> Suppose we have a set of 100 items, $90$ are good and $10$ are bad.
>
> Two items are extracted simultaneously, and their quality is checked. What are the different possible events, and what is each's probability?

I believe the events are $\{GG, GB, BB\}$, and that the probability of each is 
\begin{align}
P(GG) = \frac {90}{100}\cdot \frac{89}{99}\\
P(GB) = \frac {90}{100}\cdot \frac {10}{99}\\
P(BB) = \frac {10}{100}\cdot \frac {9}{99}
\end{align}

But this is wrong, as they don't add up to $1$.

What have I done wrong? If the extraction was made successively, instead of simultaneously, are the probabilities the same?

Comment: You haven't added the case of {BG} which gives the remaining 900 possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that adding that would yield $1$ as the total probability, but  I don't understand why: doesn't my computation of $P(GB)$ account for "getting 1 good and 1 bad", regardless of order?

Comment: Its because the very act of marking them as Good or Bad is basically making them different. so whether you take out the items simultaneously, or one by one, they will be treated as different.

Comment: @ABcDexter I don't understand... I thought that taking them out successively  would mean that getting $G$ first then $B$, and $B$ first then $G$ would be taken as 2 different cases, but not if they're taken simultaneously.

Comment: You could think of using both hands to choose them at the same time: $BG$ means the one in your left hand is bad and the one in your right hand is good, and $GB$ the opposite. The important fact is that they are different objects, not that one is chosen first.

Comment: Taking them out successively or at the same time shouldn't (and it doesn't) change the probabilities, since each scenario end up being exactly the same, so choose whichever way to think about it that makes it easier.